# Can one say "I am burning with questions about [a topic]"?

Tags: idioms

> I am burning with questions about XYZ topic.

To mean:

> I have a lot of questions about XYZ topic.

Possibly:

> I have a lot of *burning* questions about XYZ topic.

Is this something others will understand?

**Background**

I went to send this in an email to a colleague. It made perfect sense to me as I wrote it and I'm sure I've seen or heard this said before. But on reading back my email, I wondered if it makes sense. I looked it up (on Google) and couldn't find any obvious reference to this specific phrase...

- A google search for [*burning with questions*](https://www.google.com/search?q=burning%20with%20questions&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&oq=burning%20with%20questions&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j0l4.3463j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) brings up results of "burning questions"; especially links to a video series "[celebrity] answers Ellen's Burning Questions". This would suggest that the phrase "burning questions" is significantly more common than "burning with questions"
- A google search for [*"burning with questions"*](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=wvS2XLmHHOHQxgPoirbwBQ&q=%22burning%20with%20questions%22&oq=%22burning%20with%20questions%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30l10.12826.14824..15914...0.0..0.74.132.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i22i30.YiabeqTAFnM) (using quote marks to search for the exact phrase) is more successful, and quotes about 42,300 results, but the majority of the first page is about one single paper "Creativity and bipolar disorder: touched by fire or burning with questions?", which implies that this paper is using an unusual phrase.

Comment: "I looked it up on google but found nothing" isn't particularly helpful. What were your *exact* search parameters, and what were your results? I'll edit in what I found, but feel free to correct it.

Comment: The difference is whether it's the question or you that's *burning*.

Comment: @AndyT cheers for the edit. I had tried both of those and received the same results. You are correct that my initial summary was incomplete. I will bear in this mind for the future.

Comment: It's ungrammatical to include the word *topic* as you have. Nobody would say *questions about English* ***topic***. Is the word ***topic*** supposed to be literally in your sentence? Or do you really just mean *questions about* ***XYZ***?

Comment: A native speaker would never use “burning” as an adjective for his or her  own questions.

Comment: @GlobalCharm what a ridiculous generalisation. I am a native speaker.

Comment: @JasonBassford your comment doesn't add anything to this question. It is simply unnecessary and, sadly, highlights for me the general unfriendly atmosphere of this site. Furthermore, one **would** say _questions about this, that or the other topic_. I reused the word **topic** in order to link back to the question title. I have no idea why I am responding to you though. Bloody internet.

Comment: @oliver-clare I hadn't meant to be unfriendly, I was just trying to clarify what you had meant. It's still not clear to me if you had really meant to say, for example, *questions about English* or *questions about English* ***topic***. Since this is a site about precision in language, it could be important. If you want to link back to the title, your three example sentences could instead end with *questions about [a topic]*. I do think there's a difference in meaning between just *burning with questions* and *burning with questions about something*. So, syntax does play at least a subtle role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating two separate idioms here: *burning with [something]* and *burning questions*. That said, your phrase seemed completely natural and understandable to me as a native British English speaker, and it wasn't until googling it that I realised the phrase isn't particularly idiomatic.

Googling [*"burning with"*](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=T_W2XJKmD_-d1fAPp8-MeA&q=%22burning%20with%22&oq=%22burning%20with%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30j0j0i7i30l2j0l2j0i7i30l3j0.3722.5010..5650...0.0..0.89.154.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i30j0i10i30j0i8i30.RTZvbNd-kTU) gave me results of burning with anger/rage/desire as the most common [something]s. [Idioms.thefreedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/burn+with) gives:

> to strongly feel a certain emotion. *Pete's burning with anger because he heard the awful things that people are saying about him. I found myself burning with jealousy the first time I saw my ex-boyfriend with his new boyfriend.*

"Questions" isn't really an emotion, so we can't really say that "burning with questions" comes under that.

That said, going to [later pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22burning%20with%20questions%22&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=uva2XK7pCNac1fAPiOm84Ac&start=170&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiurofy7NbhAhVWThUIHYg0D3w4ggEQ8tMDCHs&biw=1008&bih=712) of the google search for your phrase (with quotes to search for the exact phrase) does show that it's not just a single paper that uses the phrase.

A [google ngrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=burning%20with%20questions%2C%20burning%20with%20rage%2C%20burning%20with%20desire%2C%20burning%20with%20anger%2Cburning%20questions&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cburning%20with%20questions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburning%20with%20rage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburning%20with%20desire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburning%20with%20anger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburning%20questions%3B%2Cc0) does show a bit of usage for your phrase, but not as common as the other idioms I mentioned.

My conclusion: "burning with questions" isn't as common as "burning with [emotion]" or "burning questions" but you'd be far from the first person to use it, and you'd be understood by native speakers.

Comment: One could be *burning with curiosity* because you have a lot of burning questions.

Comment: @JamesRandom - haha, good suggestion. Perhaps I should have asked this as a single-word request. Also _burning with desire_ to have my questions answered. AndyT, I appreciate this reply, thanks.

Comment: @JamesRandom - Good point. "Curiosity" isn't an emotion, and yet the ngram (link too long to post in comment) puts it in the same order of magnitude of usage as rage/anger/desire.

Comment: @AndyT Not an emotion but a "state of mind" maybe?